# gedit when used in terminal to write c-program

Tags: linux

We use gedit from terminal to write a c-program.
After the compilation of the program, gedit seems to hang.
We will have to force quit it after each compilation:

```
eg:nayanam@Nayanam-desktop:~$ gcc c2.c

^Z[1]   Killed                  gedit c2.c

[2]+  Stopped                 gedit c2.c
```

Is it because we use ^z?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You suspended it. Use in this case %2 to *de-froze* it.

When you run a program from command line, usually you can suspend it with CTRL-Z.
The system respond to you with line like

> [1]+ Stopped  gedit p.cpp

The program is *frozen*, and you can write other commands in the shell.
To give it again *life*  you can use `%1`  if the number of the job was 1, or with `fg`